# My symfony3 console does not have a server option?

Tags: symfony, php-7

I'm using php7 and symfony3.3.

When I list all of the console commands I have everything except for server.

Why would  server not even be listed in the console commands?

edited:  It's Symfony3 instead of Symfony2
[image]

Comment: What's your exact symfony2 version? How did you install it?

Comment: To the one that downvoted this question: please comment on how this question can be improved.

Comment: Hi, I pulled it down from our repo. 
It's Symfony 3.3.0-DEV (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)

Apparently it's symfony 3 !

Comment: Ther server option is just NOT there! Thanks much for any help.

Comment: Any server commands under vendor...FrameworkBundle/Command?  What do you mean by "our repo"?

Comment: Are you or have you used HVVM by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AppKernel dev env:

```
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
```

And "symfony/web-server-bundle" to composer.json